# Unable to hit breakpoints on M1 mac golang in VScode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I've tried to debug my hello world program in go and cannot get debugging to work.

I've installed via homebrew and the google website. I've tried various online config, installed delve and breakpoints just won't stick.

## Paths

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

## Configuration

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "hello.go"
        } 
    ]
}
```